# How to be sure API calls are using TLS 1.2

Tags: soap-api, .net, tls

We are using .Net to make web service calls the Salesforce API. Is there a way to know for sure that the calls are using TLS 1.2? Are there any API logs or records of the protocol is use in Salesforce we can review to be confident the change is working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your Login History (under Setup). It now includes a TLS version column. There is also an equivalent field on [LoginHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm) called TlsProtocol.

---

Another option is to change the API endpoint for a short period to one that only supports TLS 1.1 or 1.2.

E.g. change https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/32.0 to https://tls1test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/32.0. Seeing `"INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out."` or `“Content is not allowed in prolog.”` in the response indicates the connection was successful with TLS 1.1 or 1.2.

See [Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0 - How do I test the compatibility of an API (inbound) integration to Salesforce?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1)

---

See also:

- [How can I locate users making TLS connections in my org?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1#otheroptionsfortracking)
- [How to view all recent TLS 1.0 logins for an organization](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwirp4OD4IbTAhXGkpQKHfuHBTUQFgguMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.salesforce.com%2FHTViewSolution%3Fid%3D000247882&usg=AFQjCNEzpk93HyqjtuYai8bjcablsN0kRg&sig2=1pYNGJkIIoFWssJInWvsaA&bvm=bv.151325232,d.dGc) (link appears to be broken currently...)
  [Cached Content for broken Knowledge Article # 000247882](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:iX2YthrAR2QJ:https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution%3Fid%3D000247882%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk)