# Salesforce email says I'm connecting via TLS 1.0 but that protocol does not appear in login history

Tags: soap-api, .net, tls

I received an email recently that reads:

> Your org has been identified as having users or integrations still
>   connecting to Salesforce using TLS 1.0 encryption protocol during the
>   month of February.

That led me to ask an initial question around how I can figure out who is using TLS 1.0: [How to be sure API calls are using TLS 1.2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167027)

Unlike that question, this one is about the email I received from Salesforce, that seems to contradict what I am seeing in the login history. It's not about how I can pull the login history in the first place.

**I pulled the login history from Sep 2016 through Apr 2017, and all of my users (and API calls) have been using TLS 1.2.** So the email appears to contradict what the logs say. I downloaded all logs available and I filtered on the protocol column in Excel and it only has TLS 1.2. There are zero instances of TLS 1.1 or 1.0 in the log file. The log file includes activity.

Is it safe to assume that I'm only using TLS 1.2 since that is what the logs say? I'm just concerned about the Salesforce email stating otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An interesting comment from twitter on receiving the email:

> Raised a case with [Salesforce Support]. They said they are sending it to everyone. [@pranayjaiswal](https://twitter.com/pranayjaiswal/status/850066778864709632)

Case # 16169927

That would suggest you would get the email regardless of if you are still using TLS 1.0 or not. I could see how it will lead to some confusion as people try and track down the connections still using TLS 1.0.